# How to skip before filters in Rails Forem Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I would like to allow anonymous access to my forums. I am using the Forem Gem and the Devise Gem. I have a before_filter in my ApplicationController that ensures users are logged in.

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

In my own controllers I use skip_filter to allow anonymous access to actions but I do not know how to do this for the controllers in the Forem Gem.

I could move the before_filter statement from my ApplicationController into each of my own Controllers but I would rather not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best place for this would be a file inside your `app/controllers` directory at `forem/application_controller-decorator.rb` that contains this content:

```
Forem::ApplicationController.class_eval do
  skip_before_filter :authenticate_member!
end
```

You would then need to include this file using lines like this in a file called `config/initiailizers/load_decorators.rb`:

```
Dir.glob(Rails.root.join("app/**/*_decorator*.rb")) do |c|
  Rails.configuration.cache_classes ? require(c) : load(c)
end
```

This would allow you to specify other decorators as well, for any other class of Forem, if you so desired.

I stole this idea from Spree (which I work on full-time now), and I think it's pretty solid. You can see the original implementation of it [here](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/auth/lib/spree/auth/engine.rb#L12-15).

Comment: I tried this and it worked the first time I loaded the forum index. But if I refreshed the index or clicked on other forum links it redirected me to the login page.

Comment: I figured it out. The code in load_decorators.rb needs to be wrapped by Rails.application.config.to_prepare do end

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the answer Ryan, Just like to point out that the file should be:

`forem/application_controller_decorator.rb` otherwise it won't load with that initialiser code (note: underscore - not dash).

And to re-iterate, the initialiser code should be :

```
Rails.application.config.to_prepare do 
  Dir.glob(Rails.root.join("app/**/*_decorator*.rb")) do |c|
    Rails.configuration.cache_classes ? require(c) : load(c)
  end
end
```

So that it will reload on every request in development mode.

Hopefully that will save someone a few hours!